# __init__.py for subpackages

Tags: python

Trying to better understand our options utilizing subpackages within Python 3.x

```
+ myPackage
| __init__.py
|
+-subPackage1
  __init__.py
  code1.py
+-subPackage2
  __init__.py
  code2.py
+-subPackage3
  __init__.py
  code3.py
```

Looked at two examples that suggested we could do this with the **init**.py in myPakage and a description in a Python Reference Book, that didn't include a sample.

```
__all__ = ["subPackage1","subPackage2","subPackage3"]
__group1__ = ["subPackage1","subPackage2"]
__group2__ = ["subPackage1","subPackage3"]
__group3__ = ["subPackage2","subPackage3"]
```

allowing use of imports like:

```
from myPackage import group1
from myPackage import group2
from myPackage import *
```

This does not work correctly for all the subpackages.   subPackage1 works properly but subPackage2 does not work, even though they are identical at the design and **init**.py level.

We have some ideas of future "setup" and/or "configuration" work that could be included in the **init**.py file at the myPackage level which is we are investigating this first level of design.

Is it possible to have Python do imports in this fashion or are the examples we have misleading?

Comment: Interesting. I've never seen anything like `__group1__` used like that before

Comment: I've never seen that either. I don't think it's a thing.